# How to deserialize JSON to complex object in C#

Tags: c#, json, serialization

I'm trying to deserialize json result to wanted object. The result I'm getting is:

```
{
    "base": "EUR",
    "date": "2017-06-30",
    "rates": {
        "AUD": 1.4851,
        "BGN": 1.9558,
        "BRL": 3.76,
        "CAD": 1.4785
    }
}
```

I want this result to deserialize to my object:

```
public class ExchangeRates
{
    public string Base { get; set; }

    public DateTime Date { get; set; }

    public IList<Rates> Rates { get; set; }
}

public class Rates
{
    public string Name { get; set; }

    public decimal Value { get; set; }
}
```

my deserialization looks like this:

```
 using (var httpClient = new HttpClient())
 {
     var response = httpClient.GetAsync("http://api.fixer.io/latest").Result;
     var result = response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync().Result;
     var values = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<ExchangeRates>(result);
 }
```

When I run the program I get following exception:

> Newtonsoft.Json.JsonSerializationException: 'Cannot deserialize the current JSON object (e.g. {"name":"value"}) into type 'System.Collections.Generic.List`1[ConsoleApp4.Rates]' because the type requires a JSON array (e.g. [1,2,3]) to deserialize correctly.
>   To fix this error either change the JSON to a JSON array (e.g. [1,2,3]) or change the deserialized type so that it is a normal .NET type (e.g. not a primitive type like integer, not a collection type like an array or List) that can be deserialized from a JSON object. JsonObjectAttribute can also be added to the type to force it to deserialize from a JSON object.
>   Path 'rates.AUD', line 1, position 49.'

How can I deserialize JSON to my wanted object??

**UPDATE 1**

Or maybe I can just deserialize 'rates' list?

Comment: Basically, you don't have a `List<Rates>` - you have a `Dictionary<string, decimal>`

Comment: @JonSkeet Yeah I saw that using Dictionary<string, decimal> works fine, but after deserialization I need to map that dictionary to list, because all of those exchange rates I need to put to DB, so I thought maybe I can deserialize JSON to my wanted object so I don't need to map

Comment: There's nothing about them being in a dictionary which would stop you putting them into a Db

Comment: And assuming you don't care about the order, you can easily *create* a list: `rateDictionary.Select(kvp => new Rates { Name = kvp.Key, Value = kvp.Value }).ToList()`

Comment: Can you change the Json? If not, a Dictionary is the way to go

Comment: No, I can't change JSON and @JonSkeet answer is the best I got so far :)

Answer (score 3):

Take a look at your JSON, specifically `rates`:

```
"rates": {
    "AUD": 1.4851,
    "BGN": 1.9558,
    "BRL": 3.76,
    "CAD": 1.4785
}
```

This is very clearly a JSON object, as it has key-value pairs. However, looking at your code, you have defined the corresponding property (`Rates`) as an `IList`:

```
public IList<Rates> Rates { get; set; }
```

I understand your reasoning behind defining the `Rates` class. You think that by defining that class, NewtonSoft will deserialize `rates` the way you want it to. However, this is impossible because `rates` is not an array, and therefore deserializing it into any kind of `IList` is impossible.

The easiest and most clear cut solution is to use a dictionary:

```
public Dictionary<string, decimal> Rates { get; set; }
```

However, if you don't want to use a dictionary, you need to modify your JSON like so and your solution will work:

```
"rates":[  
  {  
     "Name":"AUD",
     "Value":1.4851
  },
  {  
     "Name":"BGN",
     "Value":1.9558
  },
  {  
     "Name":"BRL",
     "Value":3.76
  },
  {  
     "Name":"CAD",
     "Value":1.4785
  }
]
```

By converting `rates` to an array, and making its contents objects instead of key-value pairs, NewtonSoft can deserialize `rates` as a list, and its contents as instances of the `Rates` class.

Comment: That second piece of JSON isn't valid - you'd need each element to be an object.

Comment: Fiddeling around with the json document is a lot more of work and error prone.

Comment: @SirRufo True, but OP mentioned they didn't want to use a dictionary.

Comment: OP specified decimal in rate object, which makes sense for currency, suggested dictionary in this reply is float. Just saying :)

Answer (score 0):

I agree with the other guys comments: you should use a Dictionary. To achieve the conversion to your final object structure you can use for example an intermediary class with an explicit cast operator.

```
using System;
using Newtonsoft.Json;
using System.Collections.Generic;

public class Program
{
    public void Main()
    {
        var result = @"{
        ""base"": ""EUR"",
        ""date"": ""2017-06-30"",
        ""rates"": {
            ""AUD"": 1.4851,
            ""BGN"": 1.9558,
            ""BRL"": 3.76,
            ""CAD"": 1.4785
        }}";

        var values = (ExchangeRates) JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<TempExchangeRates>(result);


        Console.WriteLine(values.Base);
        Console.WriteLine(values.Date);

        foreach(var rate in values.Rates)
            Console.WriteLine(rate.Name + ": " + rate.
    }
}

public class TempExchangeRates
{
    public string Base { get; set; }
    public DateTime Date { get; set; }
    public Dictionary<string,decimal> Rates { get; set; }
    public static explicit operator ExchangeRates(TempExchangeRates tmpRates)
    {
        var xRate = new ExchangeRates();

        xRate.Base = tmpRates.Base;
        xRate.Date = tmpRates.Date;
        xRate.Rates = new List<Rates>();

        foreach(var de in tmpRates.Rates)
            xRate.Rates.Add(new Rates{Name = de.Key, Value = de.Value});

        return xRate;
    }
}


public class ExchangeRates
{
    public string Base { get; set; }
    public DateTime Date { get; set; }
    public IList<Rates> Rates { get; set; }
}

public class Rates
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public decimal Value { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: The end of Main() is unfinished:
    Console.WriteLine(rate.Name + ": " + rate.